# Running a test file with webdriverIo - Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully Initiali

Tags: automation, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I just started with webdriverIo but when I am running a test using the command: **npx wdio run ./wdio.conf.js --spec addremovetests.js** I am getting an Error: *Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
[0-0] `browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
[0-0] Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.*

Configuration on wdio.conf.js

```
specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'
    ],

services: ['chromedriver'],
```

These are the devdependencies within my package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/cli": "^7.20.5",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.20.5",
        "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.20.3",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.20.3",
        "chromedriver": "^103.0.0",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2",
        "wdio-wait-for": "^2.2.6"
    }
```

when I run the logintests.js file it works but does not work with the other files. I've tried changing the path of the required pages **const addremovePage = require('../pageobjects/addremove.page');** but nothing works.

This is the link of my basic project: https://gitlab.com/Lidana/webdriverio-practive.git

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: your project seems to be private and is not accessible.